# I have a problem in the reference of my 'head' node in my own LinkedList Class

Tags: java, data-structures

I had written my own Linked Class Codes with Node first and last, since there exists a Node last, I encountered problems regarding reference and pointer manipulations when I tried to manually created the `LinkedList` in the main method and test it.

I am quite familiar with the recursion implemented in the "addFirst" "addLast" and "remove" methods, but now somehow the reference to the Node first becomes null after addFirst Method.

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
  Node first,last,temp;

   public class Node{
     T value;
     Node next;

     public Node(T value, Node next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
     }

     public String toString(){
        if(next == null){
            return value.toString();
        }
        else{
            return value.toString() + " " + next.toString();
        }
     }

     public T getLL(int index){
        if(index == 0){
            return value;
        }
        if(next == null){
            throw new 
               IndexOutOfBoundsException("have reached the end of the list, none found");
        }
        return next.getLL(index-1);
     }

     public T removeLL(int x){
        if(x == 1){
            T value = next.value;
            next = next.next;
            return value;
        }
        else if(next == null){
            throw new 
              IndexOutOfBoundsException("have reached the end of the list, none found");
        }
        else{
            return next.removeLL(x-1);
        }
     }
  }

  public LinkedList(T value) {

    temp =  new Node(value,null);
    first = new Node(value,null);
    last = temp;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    /**
     * [120,110,100,90,80];
     */
    LinkedList L = new LinkedList(100);
    L.addFirst(110);
    L.addFirst(120);
    L.addLast(90);
    L.addLast(80);
    System.out.println(L.size());
    System.out.println(L.remove(0));
    System.out.println(L.last.toString());
    //return null which causes the remove method not to work.
    System.out.println(L.first);
  }

  public void addFirst(T value){
    first = new Node(value,first);
  }

  public void addLast(T value){
    Node p = first;
    if( p == null){
        first = last = new Node(value,null);
    }

    while(p.next!= null){
        p = p.next;
    }
    last.next = new Node(value,null);
    last = new Node(value,null);

  }

  public T get(int index){
    if(first == null){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("empty list");
    }

    return first.getLL(index);


  }

  public int size(){
    int c = 0;
    while(first != null){
        first = first.next;
        c++;
    }
    return c;
  }

  public T remove(int x){
    if(first == null){

        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Tried to remove from empty list");
    }
    if (x == 0) {
        T value = first.value;
        first = first.next;
        return value;
    }
    return first.removeLL(x);
  }
}
```

I expected that the Node first pointed to the first element of the `LinkedList` instead of pointing to `null`. Meanwhile, this won't affect the pointer of Node last.

Comment: sorry for the formatting of code block, now I don't even know how to delete the question and write a new one.

Comment: I ran your code. first doesn't become null as your text suggests. And the NullPointerException isn't thrown where you're telling us it's thrown. It's thrown in removeLL, and the message says: "have reached the end of the list, none found". By the way, I'm not sure what this method is supposed to do. it doesn't remove anything, that's for sure.

Comment: In your constructor, `first` and `last` should probably point at the same `Node`. Also, what is `temp`? Is it used anywhere? `removeLL` probably returns the last element, but it does not remove it.

Comment: Note that I had to remove `System.out.println(L.size());`, since there is no size() method.

Comment: your function `AddLast` looks suspicious. Try to comment the lines where you added to the end and see what happens. Suspicious lines: `last.next = new Node(value,null);  last = new Node(value,null);`

Comment: @JBNizet yeah, i made a mistake there, what i actually mean is that the Node first is pointing tot the null and that's the reason why in remove method is not working since it throws the exception as the first = null. as for the method remove, I updated the code, now it shall remove something if I am not wrong again. and size will work too

Comment: @SouXin I comment out the codes related to addLast method, it shows that its not his fault lmao.

Comment: @Thilo I created temp in order to make Node last point to the last added element，in the java visualizer it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem inside the `AddLast` function. You braking the list.
Shouldn't it be like this?

```
public void addLast(T value){
   Node p = first;
   if( p == null){
      first = last = new Node(value,null);
   }

   while(p.next!= null){
     p = p.next;
   }
   p.next = new Node(value,null);
   last = p.next;
   //last = new Node(value,null);
 }
```

**Update** Regarding your comment and updated answer.

1. Your size function is wrong:

   ```
   public int size(){
     int c = 0;
     while(first != null){
       first = first.next; // <-- now first point to the last and length is 1
       c++;
     }
     return c;
   }
   ```

When you remove the first element first is null. You have to create temporary variable to traverse your list. To check this comment the line where you calculate size.

2. Your are actually not quite right `last.next = new Node(value,null);` point to the new node. But instead of connecting again `last = last.next` your new node is gone because you create your new node for the last but `last.next` pointed to new node and hence last is not last anymore. (I think your understood what I meant)

Comment: thanks for the help.I assume both will work，original code last.next is referred to the newly added element and then changed the Node last pointer to the element, so nothing wrong with that. My real problem is that Node first is pointed to null.